# Sphinx Match Modes

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have sphinx setup and am querying a database just fine. Playing with the match modes, I cannot find the correct one.

For the example query, let's use 'batman'. This should match:

'Batman'
'Batman: The Dark Knight'

However, it only matches 
'Batman'

And a separate search 'dark knight' is required to match 'Batman: The Dark Knight'.

I am using search mode SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED (though I have tried all of them).

Index:

```
  source                  = src1
    path                    = /var/lib/sphinx/test1
    docinfo                 = extern
    charset_type            = sbcs
    enable_star = 1
    min_prefix_len = 3
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: This isn't match mode related. For a single word query, all modes would match the same documents.

Comment: So need to figure out what else is broken. Need more details of your setup. How is your index setup (in particular charset_table) and what other query settings are you using?

Comment: Here is the index: edited the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was that I wasn't returning enough results to be able to see what I was looking for. Whoops!